# erro ao executar o comando npx react-native run-android

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

Quando executo `npx react-native run-android`, que é pra iniciar o emulador Android, me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Command run-android unrecognized. Make sure that you have run npm install and that you are inside a react-native project.

O problema começou quando instalei a seguinte biblioteca `npm install --save react-native-collapsible`.

Como resolver esse erro?

Comment: Como estão os scripts do  `package.json`?

Answer (score -2):

A mensagem de erro diz que você provavelmente não está rodando esse comando de dentro da raíz do seu arquivo react native. Por via das dúvidas, faça o seguinte procedimento:

- Delete a pasta node_modules e o arquivo package-lock.json / yarn.lock
- Reabra a pasta do projeto
- Reinstale as libs usando `npm install` ou `yarn install` se tiver yarn instalado.
- Rode novamente `npx react-native run-android`